# Selenium Python - Using XPATH with Or operator

Tags: html, python-3.x, xml, selenium, xpath

I'm having an issue with using XPATH with the Or operator. (Using Selenium in Python)

```
R = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//* [contains(text(),'Word1')]" or "//* [contains(text(),'Word2')]")
```

Currently the code is only looking for Word1 and not Word2. Would like for it search for Word1 and if Word1 doesn't exist, look for Word 2.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Your "or" operator as written is part of your Python code, not part of the XPath expression, because it's outside the double-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

A much simpler expression would be:

```
R = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[contains(., 'Word1') or contains(., 'Word2')]")
```

Comment: Note that this will select all ancestor elements containing the targeted text as well.

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'Word1') or contains(.,'Word2')]
```

will select all elements that contain an immediate text node that contains the substring `'Word1'` or the substring `'Word2'`.